# Having electrical issues after driving/engine running for 25-30 minutes

Tags: electrical, ford, escape, intermittent-problems

So, as title says, after half hour roughly, my dashboard and alerts start turning on and off. There's also a constant pulsing in my lights and heat blower after starting the engine. There's a load issue somewhere, but I'm having trouble seeking out the gremlin. I have a 2010 Ford Escape XLT(V6 3.0L). Here's a list of things I've replaced so far:

New battery. (2nd, left for two days and killed brand new battery.)

Replaced every 20A≥ fuse in both fuse boxes.

Replaced 80A and 125A midi fuses.

Replaced PCM relay.

Replaced blower relay.

Replaced ac clutch relay.

Replaced battery ground.

Doubled down on engine ground (couldn't remove original).

The alternator has been replaced, and tested 14.2v, so I wish it was as simple as swapping one out. Also to be noted, my radio controls stopped working at one point, but on wheel buttons for radio still eorked. Couldn't turn off, just turn volume down to 0, even after taking my keys out, and being inside the house for over an hour. Wound up pulling the fuse for the radio/stereo amplifier entirely.

Not very great with electrical, so any advice as what to check would be great. Got a buddy coming over some point this weekend to start checking circuits, but a head start in a good direction would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ignition switch.

Does the ignition key get warm after the engine is running for awhile? If you jiggle the key, does it cause (or end) some of the problems you mentioned? Try turning the key slightly clockwise and counterclockwise too -- not enough to reach "start" or "off" but just a little. See if the symptoms get worse or better.

Comment: So, we check circuits today. These are all the fuses that shut the light off to circuit tester.